# Прыжок персонажа

Tags: c#, unity3d

Данный код получает число `1` или `0`, и запускает направление движения персонажа в зависимости от полученного числа. Я написал код прыжка по нажатию клавиши <kbd>Space</kbd> но он не работает, в чем может быть проблема? Поправьте пожалуйста, в *Unity* новичок. Весь код просто перемещает персонажа от одной стенки к другой, теперь нужен прыжок, но он не как не хочет прыгать.

```
public int charge = 0;

//Скорость движения
public Vector2 Speed = new Vector2(5, 5);
public Vector2 Speed2 = new Vector2(1, 1);

//Направление движения
public Vector2 direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);
public Vector2 direction2 = new Vector2(1, 0);
public Vector2 direction3 = new Vector2(0, 1);

private Vector2 movement;
private Vector2 movement2;
private Vector2 movement3;

public void Hit(int one)
{
    charge = charge + one;

}

public void Hit2(int mone)
{
    charge = charge - mone;
}

void Start () 
{       
}

void Update () 
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = movement3; //Прыжок персонажа
    }   

    movement = new Vector2(
        Speed.x * direction.x,
        Speed.y * direction.y);

    movement2 = new Vector2(
        Speed.x * direction2.x,
        Speed.y * direction2.y);

    movement3 = new Vector2(
        Speed2.x * direction3.x,
        Speed2.y * direction3.y);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{   
    if (charge == 0)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = movement;
    }
    else
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = movement2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Код сам по себе просто ужасный. Ну вообще, может у тебя гравитация   больше, чем сила, с которая придается персонажу по `y` координате

Answer (score 2):

`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = movement3; //Прыжок персонажа`
замени на:
`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * movement3);`

Comment: Лучше всего переписать скрипт...

Comment: А что измениться? у него я нашёл присваивания переменной `movement`

Answer (score 0):

Здесь я немного поправил код. Рефакторинг, пару переменных. В чём была же проблема. Вы когда присваивали свойству velocity значение переменной movement3 вы присваивали грубо говоря 0 потому что я не нашёл в вашем коде присваивание перемененной иное значение. Скорость 0 вот вам и результат. Я бы сделал импульс в виде AddForce потому что так лучше контролировать силу импульса. И скорость теперь будет немного более, о зато рабочей.

```
public int charge = 0;

//Скорость движения
public Vector2 Speed = new Vector2(5, 5);
public Vector2 Speed2 = new Vector2(1, 1);

//Направление движения
public Vector2 direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);
public Vector2 direction2 = new Vector2(1, 0);
public Vector2 direction3 = new Vector2(0, 1);

private Vector2 movement, movement2, movement3;

public void Hit(int giveDamage)
{
   charge += giveDamage;

}

public void Hit2(int getDamage)
{
    charge -= getDamage;
}
void Update () 
{

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * 1,4F) //Прыжок персонажа число 1.4 на скидку можете менять по мере надобности 

movement = new Vector2(
    Speed.x * direction.x,
    Speed.y * direction.y);

movement2 = new Vector2(
    Speed.x * direction2.x,
    Speed.y * direction2.y);

movement3 = new Vector2(
    Speed2.x * direction3.x,
    Speed2.y * direction3.y);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{   
     GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = (charge == 0) ? movement : movement2;
}
```